# Descarga de archivos

Tags: php

tengo archivos en formato excel que los usuarios deben poder descargarse de mi página web escrita en PHP. Cual es el procedimiento mas eficiente? convertirlos a PDF y utilizar la librería FPDF o hay mejores opciones? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, Ariel y bienvenido(a) a la comunidad. Debes de recordar que tu pregunta debe de ser más específica, debe de contener código o, ejemplificar - replicar el error que estás teniendo, asimismo como graficar un poco más tu problema. Consulta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para saber hacer una pregunta correcta y recibas la ayuda que esperas.

Comment: Gracias Fernando! Te agradezco la ayuda! Un abrazo!